# How do I find the angle $\theta$ of the line through the origin that matches the given points the best?

Tags: matrices, mean-square-error

How to find angle $\theta$, that the line passing through the origin that is the best fit for the points given below in the mean square sense makes with the horizontal axis.
$$x_1=[1\;\; 2]^T$$
$$x_2=[2\;\; 1]^T$$
$$x_3=[2\;\; 3]^T$$

Comment: The tangent of the angle is equal to the ratio of the elements

Comment: Do you mean best fit in the least squares sense?

Comment: yes, mean square sense symbalize best fit

Comment: +1 I was coming here to ask this question because I couldn't find an answer on google *boggle*

Answer (score 2):

$Y=[2\;\; 1\;\; 3]^T$
$X=[1\;\; 2\;\; 2]^T$

You want to find a $\beta$ such that $X\beta=\hat{Y}$ minimizes the squared distance from $Y$. The scalar that you are looking for is 
$\beta=(X'X)^{-1}X'Y =\frac{1}{9}\cdot 10 = \frac{10}{9}$. If you are wondering about the formula, it comes from first and second order conditions that yield a minimum for the squared residuals.  Then $\theta=arctan(\beta)$.

Comment: This seems to be working very well.  I have a sample set of points which are estimates to a linear relationship.  I also know that the origin 0,0 will always be a solution.  So this seems to be exactly what I needed.  Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If the line passing through the points makes an angle of $\theta$ with the horizontal $x-$axis, passing through the origin, the equation of the line is $y=\tan(\theta)x$.